# How to properly store years of digital picture files on linux without databases?

Tags: storage

[edit: this is about how to store tags in the files and how to use tags and date to create a useful directory tree]

I have more than ten years of digital pictures on my drives. Some of them are family souvenirs, some are travel pictures, some are personal hobbies (shots of decrepit walls, industrial landscapes, etc). I have a python script handling them, which will dedupe, rename, create thumbnails, hard-rotate, etc. Currently I use a directory tree with years (`YYYY`) as top level, and (`YYYYMM` or `YYYYMMDD` or even `YYYYMMDD_description`) as leaf folder.

But this lead to issues. For example, if I have pics of a new year's eve, it will speparate pictures taken at `20151231-2355` and at `20160101-0010`, which should be in the same `20151231_and_20160101_new_year_eve` leaf folder.

Another issue: let's say I'm travelling with my family in Vietnam, and I shoot a nice old factory, between the kids playing in water and rice paddies. Should these three pics stay in the same `201304_Vietnam_trip` leaf folder, for continuity, or should I separate them according to their theme? Or maybe I could be using the genre field in exif header? But then how to retrive these genres? Or maybe symlinks?

I'm sure there's no ideal solution but I'm interested in hearing advices from other having similar issues.

I'm not a professional photographer, and would be interested to know if there is a kind of standard way in this profession.

I need it to be scriptable, local, and not tied to any service or software. I would prefer no database, if possible. I won't upload everything to Google photo or Flickr, just to realise that their "magical face recognition" is lost as soon as I want to change service. Also, I'm on linux.

Comment: Take a look at Lightroom. It provides a catalog that lets you keep things structured the way you want but handles all the tagging you could want.  Prepare for a big up-front investment in tagging, however.

Comment: Acording to Wikipedia, Lightroom do not work on Linux, and it is using a proprietary database, so it is not good for me. Will check the other question.

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate and tried to explain how it is different: lightroom is not an answer.

Comment: What's your objection to a database? It's *clearly* the right solution to this problem.

Comment: The solution is to store the metadata within the files (EXIF, IPTC, XMP tags). Then whatever software you use can generate a database from that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Databases can be very inconvenient on Unix-like systems, where users usually exercise a lot of control over their directory structure. This applies especially if they want to synchronize their photos across multiple machines using standard Unix tools. Having read through https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/FAQ, I am fairly certain that routinely moving around your photos would eventually lead to corruption or loss of the database. Having your photos accessible from multiple machines seems impossible altogether.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate — I think it's way too broad. Unless you would be happy with the answer that "no, there is no standard way".

Comment: @mattdm I actually do have a positive answer but I cannot post it since the question is closed.

Comment: @Jules Is it "a possible answer" or is it _the_ answer? There are clearly many possibilities, and I think this just falls under http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. But if you've got something better than that, I could be convinced to vote to reopen.

Comment: @mattdm I think the question is specific enough, it seems to ask for photo management techniques and/or tools that work on Linux and which do not use a database. Of course, I can't tell if it's _the_ answer, but I know of some command-line tools that can manipulate JPEG tags. Since the OP is looking for something scriptable anyways, they may be able to put these tools together to achieve what they want.

Comment: I recommend DigiKam. Most all photo management apps will use a database of some kind, and that is certainly not a drawback.

Comment: If your basic need is to tag and then find photos by tags using command line tools, then I think exiftool is your friend. For a very basic search example with exiftool see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/search-large-collection-of-images-for-exif-tags-without-lightroom-aperture-etc NOTE - maybe this question should be marked as the duplicate?

Comment: @Jules yes you got my point, databases are inconvenient. I would accept an answer if a software used a database but also wrote all important information like tags in the files, so changing for another software or using command line tools like exiftool will work.